# Piecewise defining function, Why do i get extra 0 True?

Tags: piecewise

I have included a picture [image: Why do I get the last 0 True ?]

This happens on every Piecewise function

Comment: That's the "default case", which gives the result to be returned if none of your other conditions are satisfied by the argument `x`.

Comment: Would it be correct to write {x^2*Cot[x], True} On the last piece ?

Comment: Should be fine, yes.